# Ban a user: how to kick him out of the chat room (trigger a client side event)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a chat app which is connected to Firebase / Firestore and utilizes Firebaseanimatedlist in conjunction with the realtime database. When an admin of a group bans a user, I save his userid and restrict his access to the chat room. But consider that the user is currently in the chat room when he is banned. So how do I trigger an event client side when the userid is now saved within an array (list) in Firebase to kick him out of the chat room is is currently in?

Is FCM an option?

Comment: FCM is a service with the primary usage of push notifications. If you already have Firebase RTDB, then use it's listeners to check if the user is banned or not.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you are using the realtime aspect you can check the database whenever it is updated and if the user exists in the database either hide the content or leave the chat.